# Short method to check if integer is 0 and return a boolean

Tags: c#, integer, comparison, equality-operator

Can this be done in a better way?

```
public bool AreMoreNeeded() => EntitiesNeededCount == 0 ? true : false;
```

I am using this to check if an `integer` is 0 and return a `boolean` based on the operation result .

Comment: The answer given is probably what you were looking for but please note that shorter code does NOT mean better code!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, remove the `true` and `false`:

```
public bool AreMoreNeeded() => EntitiesNeededCount == 0;
```

the [equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators) :

> The equality operator `==` returns `true` if its operands are equal, `false` otherwise.

EDIT:

You can make it even a little more shorter and make it a property instead of a method:

```
public bool AreMoreNeeded => EntitiesNeededCount == 0;
```